# How can I create a "Best Answer" option for a forum?

Tags: 8

I need an approach to create a best answer option for question author to accept a comment as best answer in Drupal 8 Forum.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Forum comments are actual Drupal comments on a node (forum thread/post is a node) you can easily do anything that can be done to Drupal comments.

This includes tagging the comments with Taxonomy terms or using Flags.

[Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) might be the most suitable module when it comes to the feature of marking up comments.

You might need to do some custom theming or code if you need to reorder the comments based on that flag so the accepted answer comes up on top. You could also use Views to display the comments and order them based on the flag status first.

Comment: Thanks @prkos. I've tried it with flag but rest of answers(forum comments) are still available to flag even Question author flagged one of them. There must be only one best answer (one flagged comment). I couldn't solve this problem so I try to search another alternative.Maybe, I've missed something.

Comment: You can control the Flag logic with Rules. Any solution will work in a similar way. There isn't a ready-made solution to your question that I'm aware of, you have to finish building it on your own, you already have a lot of infrastructure you need ready to be used. Share alike if you build something custom :)